# Shadowrun fanfiction about a vampire-summoning website

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, shadowrun

I'm trying to track down a *Shadowrun* fanfiction I was told about, but I don't have much to go on. I've tried searching but it doesn't seem to be very well known.

The only information I have on it is:

1. There is a website that appears at midnight and when you fill out information on it, it summons a vampire.
2. The vampire is female and has red hair. She will offer a contract to get rid of any target you give her in exchange for life essence.
3. The person who summoned her trades the essence of the people she wanted to be targeted to fulfill the contract.

Not much to go on, but on the off chance anybody has come across it I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure the website summons a *vampire*, per se? Vampires in Shadowrun are humans (not metahumans) infected with a virus, which sometime grants them enhanced powers. I doubt they could be summoned, but I'm no expert. Maybe some sort of vampiric spirit.

Comment: Possibly but I'm not sure. It could literally be something as simple as it's actually just a website on the Matrix rather than anything magical